# iphone . getter of a tableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableViewController that I will present once in a while.

I have created it as a property, on .h

```
myTVC *myTable;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) myTVC *myTable;
```

then, on .m I have synthesized it and created a getter

```
@synthesize myTable = _myTable;
```

and

```
- (myTVC *) myTable {

    if (_myTable == nil) { 
        _myTable = [[myTVC alloc] init];
    }
    return _myTable;
}
```

when it is time to use I simply do

```
[self presentModalViewController:myTable animated:YES];
[myTable release];
```

as far as I thought, myTable's getter would run at this point and allocate the tableViewController, but it is not running and the app crashes telling me that I am trying to present a nil tableViewController...

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do `self.myTable` if you do `myTable` you are asseccing your iVar that is call `myTable` into which your `@property` is not store, because you are doing this : `@synthesize myTable = _myTable;` which will create an iVar call `_myTable`.

So you are doing 2 wrongs things in here.
To correct your code do the following :
remove this line : `myTVC *myTable;`
and do `[self presentModalViewController:self.myTable animated:YES];`

A 3rd thing is also strange in your code

```
[self presentModalViewController:myTable animated:YES];
[myTable release];  // <---- this line, remove it to
```

I'm not sure why that line is there since you are storing your `controller` in a @property.

and a 4th By the way
The default initializer for a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) is the following

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

You can pass `nil` if you don't have a .xib to go with it.

Comment: damn, I knew I was forgetting something!!!! Thanks. As far as I know, viewControllers respond to init too. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @DigitalRobot all subclass of NSObject will respond to init, but it's not necessary a good thing to use it, you may get some inconsistency if someone forgot to overwrite `init` to call the default initializer with the correct values.

Comment: ok, thanks. The release line was by mistake while posting to this forum. Thanks for the other tips.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
[self presentModalViewController:myTable animated:YES];
[myTable release];
```

You're not actually calling the `myTable` method.
Do

```
self.myTable = [self myTable]
```

first.  Though I don't see why you need a myTable method instead of just doing an alloc init.